# Laravel ORM relationship returns null only on id > 1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have recently found a problem.
I have 2 models, Articles and Users. i have defined the models relationships like this.

User.php

```
     public function articles()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Articles::class,'written_by');
 }
```

Article.php

```
    public function writer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id');
}
```

The problem is the relationship is accessible only whenever reading the article with id 1

**url.com/clanek/1**

[App\User not returning null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISUIe.png)

But when the url is **url.com/clanek/2**
Only "null" is given.

Comment: Can you please share your route `clanek/{id}` and controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the relation as below.

**User.php**

```
public function articles()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Articles::class,'written_by','id');
}
```

and in **Article.php** it'll be **belongsTo**

```
public function writer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'written_by','id');
}
```

Comment: works , thanks, i wonder why i did not tried that. will accept in a sec

Answer (score 0):

You have to change like this

**User.php**

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class,'written_by','id');
}
```

**Article.php**

```
public function writer(){
    return $this-> belongsTo(User::class);
}
```